# AspectJ - around advice for controller request methods not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, aspectj

Trying to invoke the around advice on all request methods (all GET and POST) in a controller package. The advice is not working for the request methods. Below is my controller and the aspect advice method.

**Also, I need to print the request mapping parameters like method type (Get or Post) and the Requested URL.**

Controller class:

```java
package net.prc.sales.web.controller;

// imports

@SessionAttributes({Dictionary.FORM_DRIVER_INFO})
@Controller
public class CustomerInfoController {
    @RequestMapping(value = Dictionary.URL_QUOTE_CUSTOMER_INFO, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView viewEsCustInfo(Model model, HttpSession session) throws SessionExpiredException {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
        // ...
    }
    // ...
}
```

Aspect advice:

```java
@Around("net.prc.sales.web.controller.*.*(..) && " + "@annotation(RequestMapping)")
public void ourAroundAdvice(ProceedingJoinPoint method) {
    System.out.println("Before-Advice Part:This is called before the method exceution.\n");
    try {
        method.proceed();
        System.out.println("After-Returning-Advice Part: This is called after the method returns nomally.\n");
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        System.out.println("After-Throwing-Advice Part: This is called after the method throws exception.\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't the controller.*.*(..) be controller..*(..)? Also, if you want to intercept all requests, you might want to take a look at HandlerInterceptors (http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/HandlerInterceptor.html) that allow you to pre- and posthandle requests to certains URLs

Comment: Just to check - Do you have spring-aop as a dependency? Have you enable aop:aspectj-autoproxy? Are you using JDK or CGlib proxies? If you are using JDK proxies, you should work with interfaces (http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-introduction-proxies)

Comment: Yes, I had aspectJ-autoproxy as enabled. It worked for me on @kriegaex answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@AleksiYrttiaho is right insofar as if you want to match subpackages you should use `net.prc.sales.web.controller..*` instead of `net.prc.sales.web.controller.*.*`. But that is not your problem here because the sample code shows that class `CustomerInfoController` is right in that package.

Furthermore you need to

- specify a return type in your pointcut's method signature,
- specify a fully qualified class name for the annotation and
- make sure that your advice's return type matches the intercepted methods' type. Your advice cannot return void if the intercepted method returns something else (in your example `ModelAndView`).

I would also recommend to re-throw the caught `Throwable` and not just swallow it.

Try something like this:

```java
@Around("execution(* net.prc.sales.web.controller..*(..)) && @annotation(net.prc.foo.bar.RequestMapping)")
public Object ourAroundAdvice(ProceedingJoinPoint thisJoinPoint) throws Throwable {
    System.out.println("Before " + thisJoinPoint);
    Object result = null;
    try {
        result = thisJoinPoint.proceed();
        System.out.println("After returning " + thisJoinPoint);
        return result;
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        System.out.println("After throwing " + thisJoinPoint);
        throw t;
    }
}
```

My recommendation is to learn AspectJ basics before doing complicated things. You could use native syntax instead of annotation style because Eclipse gives you great feedback via syntax highlighting and error messages. Then, if you have your pointcut ready, you can still convert it into @AspectJ syntax later.

---

**Update:** As for binding the annotation to an advice parameter in order to be able to access its properties, this can also be done, I just read that part of your question. First get the advice executing at all, then continue here (code untested):

```java
@Around("execution(* net.prc.sales.web.controller..*(..)) && @annotation(requestMapping)")
public Object ourAroundAdvice(ProceedingJoinPoint thisJoinPoint, RequestMapping requestMapping) throws Throwable {
    System.out.println("Before " + thisJoinPoint);
    System.out.println("  Request method = " + requestMapping.method());
    System.out.println("  Request value  = " + requestMapping.value());

    Object result = null;
    try {
        result = thisJoinPoint.proceed();
        System.out.println("After returning " + thisJoinPoint);
        return result;
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        System.out.println("After throwing " + thisJoinPoint);
        throw t;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked for me after a tiny tweak in the pointcut as below : @Around("execution(* net.prcins.esales.web.controller..*(..)) && @annotation(org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping)")

Comment: Yeah, in the the first example I just invented a package name ("foo.bar") because I dod not know your annotation's real package name. In the second example I assume that the parameter-bound annotation was imported in the aspect, thus the short form.

Comment: yeah, I just had to add the execution word in the point cut. 

I agree on the package thing, didn't mean to say about the package.

Comment: OMG, that was a copy & paste error, I am gonna fix that now. That's why it is a bad idea to just write and not compile & run sample code.